# bash: ./comp.out: Permission denied

Tags: c, linux, gcc, permissions

I am trying to write a program that compares 2 files and returns if they are equal or not.

I can only use the functions: `fork`, `dup`, `dup2`, `open`, `write`, `exec` and `read`.

When I compile the program on linux gcc, it returns :

> bash: ./comp.out: Permission denied

the code:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int CheckSimilar(char *path1, char *path2);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int returnValue = CheckSimilar(argv[1], argv[2]);

    switch (returnValue){

        case 1:
            write(1, "1\n", 3);
            break;
        case 2:
            write(1, "2\n", 3);
            break;
        case 3:
            write(1, "3\n", 3);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
* This function checks if the files are similar or similar by case     sensitive
* it gets 2 files, and returns: 3 if identical, 2 if identical but only if not
* case sensitive or 1 else.
*/
```

How can I change the permissions?

```
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ gcc -c ec11.c -o      comp.out
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ ls
comp.out  Debug  ec11.c
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ ./comp.out       /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt
bash: ./comp.out: Permission denied
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ comp.out /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt
comp.out: command not found
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ ./comp.out /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt
bash: ./comp.out: Permission denied
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ ^C
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ ls -al ./comp.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 shay shay 2640 Mar 30 10:05 ./comp.out
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ chmod ogu+x ./comp.out
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ ./comp.out /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt
bash: ./comp.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ gcc -c ec11.c -o comp.out
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ ./comp.out /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt
bash: ./comp.out: Permission denied
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ chmod ogu+x ./comp.out
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ ./comp.out /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt
bash: ./comp.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ comp.out /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt /home/shay/Downloads/input.txt
comp.out: command not found
```

Comment: Run `sudo ./comp.out`, maybe?

Comment: But I can't use commands on the terminal.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you not allowed to use them for some reason?

Comment: I am only allowed to use the functions written above, no more.                         as for the 2nd question: gcc -c ec11.c -o comp.out

Comment: *How* do you compile your program? Please show us the command(s) including all flags you use. Oh and that error is not from the compiler, but from when you try to run your program.

Comment: @Akshat: bad idea. It should not ne necessary to use `sudo` here. Check permissions with `ls -al ./comp.out`. Verify that it is executable. If it is not, execute `chmod ogu+x ./comp.out` - then retry

Comment: @Trinimon: Ooh, thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Trinimon It should not need to be verified that the file is executable, if the compiler and linker generated the program it should be executable by the current user, if it isn't then the OP isn't building the program correctly.

Comment: @John3136: Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Joachim: basically I agree, but there's an error somewhere ;) for sure, it'd be better to fix the root cause, if possible

Comment: ok, I did chmod - but now I get 
bash: ./comp.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.

Comment: @ShayChercavsky Are you actually *compiling* the source into an executable program, or are you just trying to run the source file? Or are you perhaps creating an object file? You need to ***show us how you build the source to create the program***.

Comment: I am compiling the source code to executable.
And then tries to compare 2 txt files by the executable I compiled to.

Comment: @ShayChercavsky Then ***show*** us how you do that. *Edit your question* to show the command, or commands, including all flags.

Comment: By the way, on an unrelated note you should really check if you have two arguments to the program, or else you will have *undefined behavior* as you might use the `argv` out of bounds. Check e.g. `if (argc < 3) { printf("To few arguments, must have two\n"); return 1; }` before the `CheckSimilar` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command

```
gcc -c ec11.c -o      comp.out
```

creates an *object file*, not an executable program file. Object files are the compiled [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (roughly source file with all included header files) and nothing more. It's the `-c` flags that tells the compiler fronteng program `gcc` to create an object file, so either remove the `-c` flag, or explicitly link.

So either

```
$ gcc ec11.c -o comp.out
```

*Or*

```
$ gcc -c ec11.c
$ gcc ec11.o -o comp.out
```

---

On an unrelated note, I advice you to add warning flags when compiling so the compiler will give you more warnings about things that might cause trouble when running (like undefined behaviors or logical/semantic problems). I personally use at least the flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: But now I have a different problem it says
  _shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ ./comp.out input.txt input.txtCannot read input file_

Comment: @ShayChercavsky That is another problem for another question.